# search or filter using jquery templates and MVC and .aspx [not .cshtml]

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to have a generic advanced search filter similar to the one mentioned in jQueryinAction,SecondEdition book in chapter 4.I'am using Jquery Templates with .aspx page as View in MVC3.

The parent dropdown will contain a list of values on selection of which the child dropdown [which is a template] will be populated.This child dropdown has values like contain,equal,greater than,lesser than etc.On change of this value the thrid control either a dropdown or a textbox will be added.On click of Add button one more such row will be added again.On click of remove button the corresponding row will be removed.The control's value change till the Final Search button click should be tracked.The value can be change inbetween and the row which is edited should be updated with correct values.Please help!

Thanks